# Why does this window.open work on Chrome and FF but not IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

The javascript/html below creates a small popup window to the bottom right of the users screen.  This code works on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE v9 for some reason.

In the IE9 debugger it says 
Line: 17
Error: Invalid argument.

line 17 being the line starting var win = window.open(...

In the debugger I see:

```
HTML1202: http://xyzserver:8080/path/test_popup.html is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked.
```

and

SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
test_popup.html, line 17 character 3

character being the v in var win = ...

Anyone any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function open_win(data) 
{
  var w = 200;
  var h = 200;
  var left = (screen.width - (w * 1.1)); 
  var top  = (screen.height - (h * 1.1));

  var win = window.open('', 'about:blank', 'width=' + w + ',  height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
  win.document.write("<p>Received: " + data + "</p>")
  win.focus()
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="open_win('information here')">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you try to uncheck the compatibility mode?

Comment: Fyi, opening windows for "additional information" is EXTREMELY BAD UX nowadays. Use an inline dialog instead!

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks for the inline dialog tip - I will investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var win = window.open('', '', 'width=' + w + ',  height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
```

so without `'about:blank'` because Microsoft does not support a name as second argument.

or you should say: `window.open('_blank', '', 'width='...)....etc` giving the name as a first argument.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `about:blank` as the first argument instead of the second one (which is the window name that apparently may not contain a .`:` in IE)